# how to open new tabs for items in $ionicActionSheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and angular js for simple mobile app. I used [$ionicActionSheet](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/) for social links. $ionicActionSheet is working fine but I want to add social links url to it and on click open it to new tab. I tried using a tag and using $window.open() function but to no avail.

Code:

```
app.controller('socialController', function($scope, $ionicActionSheet, $window) {

    $scope.showActionsheet  = function() {
        $ionicActionSheet.show({
            titleText: 'Social',
            buttons: [
                { text: '<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i> Facebook </a>' },
                { text: '<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"> <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i> Twitter </a>' },
                { text: '<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"> <i class="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i> Linkedin </a>'},
                { text: '<a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"> <i class="icon ion-social-youtube"></i> Youtube </a>' }
            ],
            cancelText: 'Cancel',
            buttonClicked: function(index) {

                /*if(index == '0') {
                    $window.open("https://www.facebook.com", "_blank");
                    return true;
                } else if(index == '1') {
                    $window.open("https://twitter.com", "_blank");
                    return true;
                } else if(index == '2') {
                    $window.open("https://www.linkedin.com", "_blank");
                    return true;
                }else {
                    $window.open("http://www.youtube.com", "_blank");
                    return true;
                }*/
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong or how to solve this issue. Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What doesn't work if you use the `$window.open` in `buttonClicked`?

Comment: @devqon new tab doesn't open in mobile devices.

Comment: I think you have to install the inAppBrowser plugin for that

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Code:

```
app.controller('socialController', function($scope, $ionicActionSheet, $window) {

    $scope.showActionsheet  = function() {
        $ionicActionSheet.show({
            titleText: 'Social',
            buttons: [
                { text: '<i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i> Facebook' },
                { text: '<i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i> Twitter' },
                { text: '<i class="icon ion-social-linkedin"></i> Linkedin'},
                { text: '<i class="icon ion-social-youtube"></i> Youtube' }
            ],
            cancelText: 'Cancel',
            buttonClicked: function(index) {

                if(index == '0') {
                    window.open("https://www.facebook.com", "_system", "location=yes");

                } else if(index == '1') {
                    window.open("https://twitter.com", "_system", "location=yes");

                } else if(index == '2') {
                    window.open("https://www.linkedin.com", "_system", "location=yes");

                }else {
                    window.open("http://www.youtube.com", "_system", "location=yes");

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
})
```

But I still don't know what exactly "location=yes" does.